# How can I convert a Sql Server Query with Outer Apply into Linq C#?

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.0

I have a table that has the result of some conversions and i need to join the converted values with all the actual values in my backend using a approximate filter.

I could do it with a query like this:

```
with values_to_search as (
    select 13 as quantity
    union
    select 21 as quantity
    union
    select 30 as quantity
)

select
    vts.quantity,
    converted.ConvertedQuantityMg
from values_to_search vts
OUTER APPLY (
    select top 1
        cd.ConvertedQuantityMg
    from MyConversion cd
    where
        cd.Quantity <= vts.quantity
    order by cd.Quantity desc
) as converted
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2ab17a/3)

*Obs: The `values_to_search` cte is just to simulate the data that are going to be queried.*

The only solution I could think of, doing it in a single query, is to get all data in memory filtering by range and getting the exact converted value in memory.

Something like:

```
var valuesToFilter = new List<int>() { 13, 21, 30 };

var results = _context.Set<MyConversion>()
    .Where(conversion => conversion.Quantity >= valuesToFilter.Min() &&
                         conversion.Quantity <= valuesToFilter.Max())
    .ToList();

foreach (var val in valuesToFilter )
{
   var convertedValue = results.Where(conversion => conversion.Quantity <= val)
                               .OrderByDescending(conversion => conversion.Quantity)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

There's a way to translate the above sql query to Linq?
I'm using EF Core 2.6.